# Issue with object items in Vaadin Fusion combo box

Tags: combobox, vaadin, vaadin21, vaadin-fusion, hilla

I have a `vaadin-combo-box` in my Fusion v21 app which I try to populate with objects that contain a name and a value. So, I want to display the `name` property in the dropdown of the combo box and when I select a value, it should put the `value` in my entity which is bound by a `Binder`.

```
private binder = new Binder<SamplePerson, SamplePersonModel>(this, SamplePersonModel);
...
<vaadin-combo-box
    .items="${[{name:'Name1', value:'Value1'},{name:'Name2', value:'Value2'}]}"
    @value-changed="${(e: CustomEvent) => console.log(e.detail.value)}"
    item-label-path="name"
    item-value-path="value"
    ...="${field(this.binder.model.lastName)}">
</vaadin-combo-box>
```

My entity:

```
@Data
public class SamplePerson {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Nonnull
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
}
```

When I change the value, I can see in the console log, that it is displaying the correct value. But when I inspect my entity in the `submitTo` method, I get the following:

```
// expected: lastName: 'Value1'
// but got:
lastName: {name: 'Name1', value: 'Value1'}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

(I have refactored a start app from Vaadin using the Person form template.)

Comment: I tried it with Vaadin 22 and it works fine. Which Vaadin version are you using?

Comment: I am using v22 as well. I have added a test app here: https://github.com/rna2i/vaadin-combobox-binder-test

Comment: Issue has been reported here: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/3175